# How to change text multiple times at different intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let's say you have something like this..

HTML:

```
<p id="text"></p>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#text').html("First sentence");}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#text').html("Second sentence");}, 2000);
```

Is there any way you can display like ten of these sentences without having to write the same line of code ten times? I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a closure over `i` and throw a party.

```
var $text = $("#text");
var numbers = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth"];

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $text.html(numbers[index-1] + " sentence");
    }, i * 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/9z4r1qqk/

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. What does the (i) do at the end of the function?

Comment: What's happening is that the anonymous function is being immediately invoked (hence, the `()` after the function close. The `i` inside those parenthesis is coming from the `i` in the outer for loop. The reason we need to do this is because we must capture the value of `i` *the moment* the loop is executing. Otherwise, we'll always get the final value of `i`. Also notice that `index`,  (the argument in the anonymous function) is the value of `i` at each iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10 ; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {$('#text').html("Sentence #" + i);}, i * 1000);
}
```

If you don't need the sentence to have exactly that format.

Comment: setTimeout isn't a precise timer so it could still fire the callbacks in a different order. Although highly unlikely.

Comment: Valid point @JonKoops , I figured that since the granularity in this case is 1 sec it shouldn't become a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work as `i` changes in context before the function gets called. The functions created all share the same `i` context. In addition, OP asked for variable timing.

Comment: @Ouroborus From the code he posted I assumed 1 second interval. But the other point is valid, it might be better to wrap it in a closure to make sure the context is maintained, although my testing does not show any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like `map` is what You are looking for.

```
const $elem = $('#text');

[
  ['First sentence', 1000],
  ['Second sentence', 2000],
].map(([text, delay]) => setTimeout(() => $elem.text(text), delay));
```

It would also be a good idea to store a pointer to an element in a variable, so the browser would do the search just once.

You also might want to switch to `text` method if the content You want to set is just strings.

**Disclaimer**: this code is written in ES6, so it won't be working in IE (but will in Edge) and Safari.

Comment: You are not doing it ten times here.

Comment: I believe the main goal was not to do it exactly ten times, but rather to set different text with certaint delays.

Comment: @MarioLopez this is easy enough to extend to more cases.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев I would use an array of objects instead of an array of arrays, to improve readability. Something like `{text: "First sentence", delay: 1000}`, so you can access `item.text` and `item.delay`.

Comment: And this is ES6, which is great, but not supported by all browsers.

Comment: I fully agree that it will make the function part more clear, but it will bloat the data part at the same part. As soon as destructuring operator will be supported by major browsers, we could do just `data.map([text, delay] => setTimeout($elem.text(text), delay)`.

Comment: Brevity in your code doesn't necessarily equal more readable code.

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function as an argument, instead you pass in the results of `$elem.text()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sentences = ['First sentence', 'Second sentence', 'Some other sentence'];
var timerId = null;

function nextSentence() {
  var sentence = sentences.shift();
  $('#text').text(sentence);

  if (sentences.length == 0) {
    window.clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}

timerId = window.setInterval(nextSentence, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Just add the sentences you want to display to the `sentences` variable and they should change approximately every second.

If this is all you need to do, you can probably remove the jQuery dependency by replacing `$('#text').text(sentence);` with `document.getElementById('text').textContent = sentence;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sequence = [
  ['first sentence',1000],
  ['second sentence',2000]
];

var $target = $('#text');

sequence.map(function(v,i,a){
  return setTimeout(function(){
    $target.innerHtml(v[0]);
  },v[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will run as a loop and only show the next sentence after the last one is complete.

[Sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/efdw0Lsr/1/)

```
var a = [
  "test 1",
  "test 2",
  "test 3",
  "test 4",
  "test 5"
];

(function update(idx) {

    $("#text").html(a[idx]);
    setTimeout(update, 1000, ((++idx) % a.length));

})(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to type the same thing multiple times, perhaps in multiple places, create a plugin that is easy to use instead

```js
$.fn.queuedText = function(text, delay) {
    var self = this;
    text = Array.isArray(text) ? text : [text];
    
    $.each(text, function(_, txt) {
       self.delay(delay).queue(function (next) { 
           self.text(txt);
           next(); 
       });
    });
    
    return self;
}

// To be used as ..........->

$('#text').queuedText([
    "First sentence",
    "Second sentence",
    "Third sentence",
    "Fourth sentence",
    "Fifth sentence",
    "Sixth sentence",
    "Seventh sentence",
    "Eight sentence",
    "Ninth sentence",
    "Tenth sentence"
], 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```